# Find Big Theta $\Theta$ of generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the generating function:
$$F(x) = \frac{x^{2}}{(x^{2}-9x+14)(x^{2}+2x-3)}-\frac{x^{1}}{(x^{2}-9x+14)(x^{2}+2x-3)} $$
I am looking to find a $\Theta$ approximation of this sequence. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

I think you can say that $F(x)$ is equal to $x²/(x-2)(x-7)(x+3)(x-1)$ so you take the smallest roots and you say that $F(x)$ is big theta of $1$ (constant).
Hope it will be ok for Rudiger ^^

Comment: You misunderstood: the question is about the **sequence** for which $F$ is the generating function. Not about $F$ itself.